# Disable processors in power save mode

Tags: power-management, cpu

I have a laptop with 4-core Intel processor on Ubuntu 16.04. When I use it cores consum too much electricity and laptop's battery discharges too fast. I want to have availability to temporarily disable few processors, automatically when I use powersave mode or at least manually. How can I do that? Is this possible?

Comment: It is very unlikely you have 4 cores on your laptop. There are two cores with hyperthreading that are seen as 4. And Intel `pstate` does everything. Your power consumption problem is somewere else. So it is an  [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have 4 cores, not 2 + 2 threads.

Comment: What is your CPU?

Comment: Agree with @Pilot6, your power problem is somewhere else. Also, there is a problem with some computers where if you disable CPUs and go through a suspend/resume cycle, the CPUs that are supposed to be off-line will actually consume maximum power. Very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it manually:

Procedure when using Linux

When starting up your PC, you should find the Grub menu, which is responsible for launching Linux. Select the entry you want to use, press the E key and a menu will appear (depending on the version used).

```
title       Ubuntu 7.10, kernel 2.6.22-14-generic


root         (hd0,5)     
kernel       /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.22-14-generic root=UUID=a8a39729-9d2a-425b-b84b-ecc5c7dad104 ro quiet splash     
initrd         /boot/initrd.img-2.6.22-14-generic     
quiet
```

Using the arrow keys, go the line beginning with the word "kernel" and press E again.

Be aware that you are editing the line, which defines the path to your Linux kernel (core). At the end of the line, add the following command:

```
maxcpus=1
```

The end result should be:

```
kernel  /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.22-14-generic root=UUID=a8a39729-9d2a-425b-b84b-ecc5c7dad104 ro quiet maxcpus=1
```

Note: que ro, quiet and maxcpus are the parameters sent to the core when starting up Linux.

Press the B key to start Linux.

Source: http://ccm.net/faq/616-multicore-cpu-how-to-disable-a-core

Comment: You can disable CPUs (not CPU 0) on-the-fly: Example: `echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online` . However, be aware of [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121051) problem (which does not occur on all computers).

Comment: As you have already stated, some computers will do the exact opposite after reboot. I tried to give solution with maximum possible respect to hardware.